# How to match regex only for certain string literals?

Tags: regex

I want to create `regex` that matches a digit, followed by the string `A`, `B` or `AB`.

Should match:

```
0A
0B
0AB
```

not:

```
0AA
0BB
0BA
```

I started as follows, but that would also match the values below that I don't want to match:

```
[0-9][AB]+
```

Of course this is due to the `[AB]+` group. But how can I only match like `A|B|AB`?

Comment: What about `"0ABA"`?

Comment: Sometimes simplest is best: depending on requirements, I suggest `^\d(?:A|B|AB)$` or `\d(?:A|B|AB)\b`. They are efficient and read well.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I like it. Simplicity over elegance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `[AB]+` matches 1 or more times either A or B, and the pattern is unanchored to is can partially match in `0ABC`

You can match either A followed by an optional B, or a single B.

```
^\d(?:AB?|B)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EwFx4P/1)

Or with word boundaries:

```
\b\d(?:AB?|B)\b
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use this regex:

```sh
^\d(?:[AB]|AB)?$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aE9SMG/1)

It matches a digit at the start followed by `A` or `B` using character class `[AB]` or just `AB` as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Or this way:

```
\dA?B?
```

A digit with 0 or 1 "A" and 0 or 1 "B".

Oups, does not work, as it can match single digit with no letter.

Comment: That matches `'0'`.